# Why after install VirtualBox my terminal and software center remove

Tags: 14.04, unity, virtualbox

I installed VirtualBox-4.3.26 and after install unity is broken and  Launcher  and terminal are removed along with Software Center?
My windows panel is not showing , for example my windows  does not close and minimize and maximize.

How to restore my Desktop?

Comment: From where did you install VirtualBox-4.3.26? Did you downloaded and manually installed .deb package?

Comment: Yes, but not download from Oracle center. downloaded from another site.  https://licensing.psu.ac.th/virtualbox-4-3-26-released/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok the problem could be that you may have installed package for different architecture from you OS architecture.

To check which architecture is your OS, write in terminal:

```
uname -a
```

Result for 32-bit Ubuntu:

> Linux discworld 2.6.38-8-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 11 03:31:50 UTC 2011 i686 i686 **i386** GNU/Linux

whereas the 64-bit Ubuntu will show:

> Linux discworld 2.6.38-8-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 11 03:31:50 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 **x86_64** GNU/Linux

So after you know the correct architecture, first you need to remove the package that you have installed:

```
sudo apt-get purge virtualbox*
```

The download and install proper package:

For 32 bit OS `virtualbox-4.3_4.3.26-98988~Ubuntu~raring_i386.deb`

For 64 bit OS `virtualbox-4.3_4.3.26-98988~Ubuntu~raring_amd64.deb`

Possible duplicate as [VirtualBox 4.3 on Ubuntu 13.10 breaks Unity and Terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/455932/virtualbox-4-3-on-ubuntu-13-10-breaks-unity-and-terminal)